# for loop acts abnormally in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Consider the following loop in C:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i > 0; i++);
```

After `i` reaches `INT_MAX`, it will turn `INT_MIN` at increment. Then `i > 0` evaluates
false, and the for loop will terminate.

However, the same for loop will not terminate in Arduino, since `i > 0` compares false
even if `i` is `-32768`.

Why is that?

PS. I'm using a Mega 2560 with Arduino version 1.0.5.
PPS. int is indeed 16 bit on Mega 2560
PPPS. The complete sketch below:

```
void setup () {
  int i;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (i = 1; i > 0; i++);
}

void loop () {
  Serial.println(100);
}
```

And I won't see any thing in the Serial Monitor

Comment: Arduino loops all the time in loop() function. Why use For loop?

Comment: Can you show a complete small sketch that reproduces the problem, including how you detect whether the for loop has terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassembling the setup function gives:

```
0000014a <setup>:
 14a:   80 e3           ldi r24, 0x30   ; 48
 14c:   94 e0           ldi r25, 0x04   ; 4
 14e:   40 e8           ldi r20, 0x80   ; 128
 150:   55 e2           ldi r21, 0x25   ; 37
 152:   60 e0           ldi r22, 0x00   ; 0
 154:   70 e0           ldi r23, 0x00   ; 0
 156:   42 d2           rcall   .+1156      ; 0x5dc <_ZN14HardwareSerial5beginEm>
 158:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0x158 <setup+0xe>
```

so now it's clear: avr-gcc thinks the `i > 0` in `for(i = 1; i > 0; i++)` will never evaluates false and optimised the exit condition away.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, 'int' is also 32-bit on Arduino. It takes time to complete 2^31 iterations. You may change 'int' to 'short' and it should terminate as expected.

Comment: Er... int is 16-bit on Mega 2560 (but not on Due) ~_~

Comment: Ok, you may use "gcc -S <prog.c>" to generate the assembly code and see if there is an error. It could also be due to optimization, which you can turn off by adding the flag "-O0". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

when int is defined, by default, its size is assumed to be of 16 bit by compiler.

But when you increment it beyond 32767 i.e.

```
int i=32767;
i++;
```

The size of 'i' is automatically increased to 32 bit. This is because the size is not specified in the declaration.

This causes your program not to stop at 32767.

Hence if you want to stop the for loop at 32767,

**you have to specifically declare it as**

```
short int i;
```

If you want to verify this, you can try following

```
short int x;
for(x=1; x>0; x++)
{
  mySerial.println(x);
}
```

AND

```
int x;
for(x=1; x>0; x++)
{
  mySerial.println(x);
}
```